# javascript regex match duplicate

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have string and want to capture a fragment by regex as:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\s?.{0,2}the.{0,2}\s?)", "i");
var str= " the apple the apple the apple the apple the apple the apple the apple"
alert(str.match(regex))
```

The goal is to capture the first "max 3 symbol with(within) space" + "the" + "max 3 symbol with(within) space"

I dont understand why result is duplicated ------>  the a, the a

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The goal is to capture the first "max 3 symbol with(within) space" + "the" + "max 3 symbol with(within) space"

Comment: That could be because of the capturing group.

Comment: I think you mean `new RegExp("(\\s?.{0,2}the.{0,2}\\s?)", "i");`  You're using strings to compile the regex, not writing the regex directly as in `/(\s?.{0,2}the.{0,2}\s?)/i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\s?.{0,2}the.{0,2}\s?)", "i");
                        ^                     ^   unnecessary capturing group.
```

**[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** will handle the capturing group around the expression for you.

Your regex should be:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\s?.{0,2}the.{0,2}\s?", "i");
```